# Css help for positioning elements on screen

Tags: css, layout, grid

I need to position a few elements responsively on the screen for my chat application. I have tried the grid system, but it doesn't seem to be working out.

I need a layout like the following:
[image]

The typing area shows which user is typing and online shows which user is online. Messages show the messages and chat contains the input. Using the grid system I got :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The typing for one should come above the input, and the input should not take the entire space. The chat area is like this:

```
<form id="form" action="">
    <div id="typing"> </div>
    <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Css:

```
    #form {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        padding: 0.25rem;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        height: 3rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }

    #input {
        border: none;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        flex-grow: 1;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        margin: 0.25rem;
    }

    #input:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    #form>button {
        background: #333;
        border: none;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        margin: 0.25rem;
        border-radius: 3px;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIY86.png

Comment: I cant at the moment see where you are using the grid system. Could you make your code into a runnable snippet - it makes it easier for us to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the layout, use a flexbox to divide the left and right (online) panel

```
<div style="display:flex;width:100%;height:100vh">
    <div id="left-side">
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <div id="typing"></div>
        <div id="chat"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="online"></div>
</div>
```

The left-side div should have display:block, and as for the measurements choose whatever is to your liking.

Color coded the end result should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvD7k.png)